# Beginner algebra question: Solve for x: (-3/2)x − -4 =?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a very very new beginner and i would like to know the answer to this equasion
Solve for x: (-3/2)x − -4 = 13

A. 6      B. -6      C. 3     D. -3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to question:
$$\frac{-3}{2}x − -4 = 13$$
Make - 4 to the right side
$$\frac{-3}{2}x=9$$
Multiply both sides with two:
$$-3x=18$$
Divide both sides throught -3:
$$x=-6$$
Thus the answer is **B**
Hope this helps $$:)$$

Comment: Hope they are not doing an exam.